# Add BullsEye to Image (changing pixels)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add a target (bullseye) to an image without the use of importing python functions, it is proving to be rather difficult however I believe I need to define a circle through use of code.  It should be done by changing the pixels as opposed to importing functions.

Thanks

Needs to be in the centre of an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add more information here -  how is your image represnted in Python? Normally for porduction code, dealing with images is done through 3rd party modules, each of which have a way to draw or change different pixels. If you are using none you have to define your image reading and writting code (or  a way to display the image on the screen).

Anyway, doing all of that without any "importing"  will be quite artificial, though feasible. 
Maybe you should use pnm files which have a minimum of encoding required.

That said, you could represent the image in memory as a bytesarray object, and use math.sin and math.cos (you will have to import those, or resort to a "raytracing" approach which can render the circle based on x**2 + y * 2 = r ** 2  ) to draw your circle.